# what is right syntax to access page if condition in session like this?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

excuse me
I have little problem 
what is right syntax to  access page if I have condition like this (status) in session
if status=0 and 2 can be access pegawai

this if status=0,

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('STATUS')==0) {?> <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>pegawai"><i class="icon-user"></i>Pegawai</a></li><?php } ?>
```

so I want this page can be access if status 0 and 2
what syntax that should be used?

I have make this

```
<?php 
if($this->session->userdata('STATUS')==0) {
?> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>pegawai"><i class="icon-user"></i>Pegawai</a></li>
<?php 
} 
?>
<?php 
if($this->session->userdata('STATUS')==2) {
?> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>pegawai"><i class="icon-user"></i>Pegawai</a></li>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

so if status 0 and 2 can be acces but it's not efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to use an `Or` [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)?

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('STATUS')==0 || $this->session->userdata('STATUS')==2): ?> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>pegawai"><i class="icon-user"></i>Pegawai</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answering but also down-voting this and suggesting you close it.  Shows a lack of searching for the answer.  You might want to read an intro to coding PHP.

Comment: sorry if my question confusing
but your answer has been answered my question
thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Make it simpler like this

```
<?php
if( $this->session->userdata('STATUS')==0 || $this->session->userdata('STATUS')==2) {
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>pegawai"><i class="icon-user"></i>Pegawai</a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```